# Picturebox Not functioning according to its purpose in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, forms, vb.net-2010

I am really puzzled about my program right now because it acts really different according to its purpose what I am trying to do is that I if the text in textbox in the previous form is the same as the text in the textbox on the next form it will show picture1 which is a checkmark otherwise it will show the picture2 which is a crossmark but what happens is instead it will act correctly if one of the text is empty or null but if all textboxes has a value whether the texts on the texboxes satisfies the statement it will always show the picture2 which is a crossmark. I hope you can help me.Thanks in advance.

```
Imports System.Convert
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox
Imports System.Drawing.Image

Public Class Form4
Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form
Private frm1 As Form1
Private frm2 As Form2
Public frm3 As Form3
Private frm4 As Form4
Private frm5 As Form5


Private Sub Form4_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim lbl3 As Integer
    lbl3 = CInt(lbl3)

    Me.Visible = False


End Sub
Public Sub New1(ByVal callerInstance As Form1)

    ' Call required if you add your constructor manually
    InitializeComponent()

    ' save the instance of the Me variable passed to this constructor
    frm1 = callerInstance
End Sub
Public Sub New5(ByVal callerInstance As Form2)

    ' Call required if you add your constructor manually
    InitializeComponent()

    ' save the instance of the Me variable passed to this constructor
    frm2 = callerInstance
End Sub
Public Sub New4(ByVal callerInstance As Form3)

    ' Call required if you add your constructor manually
    InitializeComponent()

    ' save the instance of the Me variable passed to this constructor
    frm3 = callerInstance
End Sub
Public Sub New3(ByVal callerInstance As Form4)

    ' Call required if you add your constructor manually
    InitializeComponent()

    ' save the instance of the Me variable passed to this constructor
    frm4 = callerInstance
End Sub
Public Sub New5(ByVal callerInstance As Form5)

    ' Call required if you add your constructor manually
    InitializeComponent()

    ' save the instance of the Me variable passed to this constructor
    frm5 = callerInstance
End Sub



Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim frm1 As Form1 = Form1
    Dim frm2 As Form2 = Form2
    Dim frm3 As Form3 = Form3
    Dim frm5 As Form5 = Form5




        frm5.Label21.Text = frm1.TextBox1.Text
        frm5.Label21.ForeColor = Color.Black



        frm5.Label22.Text = frm1.TextBox2.Text
        frm5.Label22.ForeColor = Color.Black



        frm5.Label23.Text = frm1.TextBox3.Text
        frm5.Label23.ForeColor = Color.Black


        frm5.Label24.Text = frm1.TextBox4.Text
        frm5.Label24.ForeColor = Color.Black



        frm5.Label25.Text = frm1.TextBox5.Text
        frm5.Label25.ForeColor = Color.Black



        frm5.Label26.Text = frm1.TextBox6.Text
        frm5.Label26.ForeColor = Color.Black


        frm5.Label27.Text = frm1.TextBox7.Text
        frm5.Label27.ForeColor = Color.Black



        frm2.Label28.Text = frm1.TextBox8.Text
        frm2.Label28.ForeColor = Color.Black



        frm5.Label29.Text = frm1.TextBox9.Text
        frm5.Label29.ForeColor = Color.Black


        frm5.Label30.Text = frm1.TextBox10.Text
        frm5.Label30.ForeColor = Color.Black



        frm5.Label31.Text = frm1.TextBox11.Text
        frm5.Label31.ForeColor = Color.Black


        frm5.Label32.Text = frm1.TextBox12.Text
        frm5.Label32.ForeColor = Color.Black



        frm5.Label33.Text = frm1.TextBox13.Text
        frm5.Label33.ForeColor = Color.Black



        frm5.Label34.Text = frm1.TextBox14.Text
        frm5.Label34.ForeColor = Color.Black


        frm5.Label35.Text = frm1.TextBox15.Text
        frm5.Label35.ForeColor = Color.Black


        frm5.Label36.Text = frm1.TextBox16.Text
        frm5.Label36.ForeColor = Color.Black



        frm5.Label37.Text = frm1.TextBox17.Text
        frm5.Label37.ForeColor = Color.Black



        frm5.Label38.Text = frm1.TextBox18.Text
        frm5.Label38.ForeColor = Color.Black


        frm5.Label39.Text = frm1.TextBox19.Text
        frm5.Label39.ForeColor = Color.Black



        frm5.Label40.Text = frm1.TextBox20.Text
    frm5.Label40.ForeColor = Color.Black
    Dim tb1 As TextBox = frm3.TextBox1

    Dim tb2 As TextBox = frm3.TextBox2
    Dim tb3 As TextBox = frm3.TextBox3
    Dim tb4 As TextBox = frm3.TextBox4
    Dim tb5 As TextBox = frm3.TextBox5
    Dim tb6 As TextBox = frm3.TextBox6
    Dim tb7 As TextBox = frm3.TextBox7
    Dim tb8 As TextBox = frm3.TextBox8
    Dim tb9 As TextBox = frm3.TextBox9
    Dim tb10 As TextBox = frm3.TextBox10

    If tb1.Text IsNot Nothing Then
        If (frm1.TextBox2.Text.Equals(tb1.Text)) And frm1.TextBox2.Text = tb1.Text Then
            frm5.PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("D:\checkmark.jpg")

        Else
            frm5.PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("D:\crossmark.jpg")

        End If
    Else
        frm5.PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("D:\crossmark.jpg")
    End If
    If tb2.Text IsNot Nothing Then
        If (frm1.TextBox4.Text.Equals(tb2.Text)) And frm1.TextBox4.Text = tb2.Text Then
            frm5.PictureBox2.Image = Image.FromFile("D:\checkmark.jpg")

        Else

            frm5.PictureBox2.Image = Image.FromFile("D:\crossmark.jpg")
        End If
    Else
        frm5.PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("D:\crossmark.jpg")
    End If
    If tb3.Text IsNot Nothing Then
        If (frm1.TextBox6.Text.Equals(tb3.Text)) And frm1.TextBox6.Text = tb3.Text Then
            frm5.PictureBox3.Image = Image.FromFile("D:\checkmark.jpg")
        Else

            frm5.PictureBox3.Image = Image.FromFile("D:\crossmark.jpg")
        End If
    Else

        frm5.PictureBox3.Image = Image.FromFile("D:\crossmark.jpg")
    End If
    If tb4.Text IsNot Nothing Then
        If (frm1.TextBox8.Text.Equals(tb4.Text)) And frm1.TextBox8.Text = tb4.Text Then

            frm5.PictureBox4.Image = Image.FromFile("D:\checkmark.jpg")
        Else
            frm5.PictureBox4.Image = Image.FromFile("D:\crossmark.jpg")
        End If
    Else

        frm5.PictureBox3.Image = Image.FromFile("D:\crossmark.jpg")
    End If
    If tb5.Text IsNot Nothing Then
        If (frm1.TextBox10.Text.Equals(tb5.Text)) And frm1.TextBox10.Text = tb5.Text Then

            frm5.PictureBox5.Image = Image.FromFile("D:\checkmark.jpg")
        Else
            frm5.PictureBox5.Image = Image.FromFile("D:\crossmark.jpg")
        End If
    Else

        frm5.PictureBox3.Image = Image.FromFile("D:\crossmark.jpg")
    End If
    If tb6.Text IsNot Nothing Then
        If (frm1.TextBox12.Text.Equals(tb6.Text)) And frm1.TextBox12.Text = tb6.Text Then

            frm5.PictureBox6.Image = Image.FromFile("D:\checkmark.jpg")
        Else
            frm5.PictureBox6.Image = Image.FromFile("D:\crossmark.jpg")
        End If
    Else

        frm5.PictureBox3.Image = Image.FromFile("D:\crossmark.jpg")
    End If
    If tb7.Text IsNot Nothing Then
        If (frm1.TextBox14.Text.Equals(tb7.Text)) And frm1.TextBox14.Text = tb7.Text Then
            frm5.PictureBox7.Image = Image.FromFile("D:\checkmark.jpg")
        Else
            frm5.PictureBox7.Image = Image.FromFile("D:\crossmark.jpg")
        End If
    Else

        frm5.PictureBox3.Image = Image.FromFile("D:\crossmark.jpg")
    End If
    If tb8.Text IsNot Nothing Then
        If (frm1.TextBox16.Text.Equals(tb8.Text)) And frm1.TextBox16.Text = tb8.Text Then

            frm5.PictureBox8.Image = Image.FromFile("D:\checkmark.jpg")
        Else
            frm5.PictureBox8.Image = Image.FromFile("D:\crossmark.jpg")
        End If
    Else

        frm5.PictureBox3.Image = Image.FromFile("D:\crossmark.jpg")
    End If
    If tb9.Text IsNot Nothing Then
        If (frm1.TextBox18.Text.Equals(tb9.Text)) And frm1.TextBox18.Text = tb9.Text Then
            frm5.PictureBox9.Image = Image.FromFile("D:\checkmark.jpg")
        Else
            frm5.PictureBox9.Image = Image.FromFile("D:\crossmark.jpg")
        End If
    Else

        frm5.PictureBox3.Image = Image.FromFile("D:\crossmark.jpg")
    End If
    If tb10.Text IsNot Nothing Then
        If (frm1.TextBox20.Text.Equals(tb10.Text)) And frm1.TextBox20.Text = tb10.Text Then

            frm5.PictureBox10.Image = Image.FromFile("D:\checkmark.jpg")
        Else

            frm5.PictureBox10.Image = Image.FromFile("D:\crossmark.jpg")
        End If
    Else

        frm5.PictureBox10.Image = Image.FromFile("D:\crossmark.jpg")
    End If


    If frm5 IsNot Nothing Then
        frm5.Visible = False

        frm5.Show() 'Show Second Form  

        Me.Hide()
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Form5HasBeenClosed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As FormClosedEventArgs)
    Throw New NotImplementedException
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Try using `If tb10.Text = ""` instead of `If tb10.Text IsNot Nothing`

Comment: Maybe you mean `If Not tb10.Text = ""`

Comment: @Jens hi ma'am/sir it still the same :(

Comment: @Arman I added not just right now and some of the picturebox disappeared

Comment: Also try to refactor your code.

Comment: @Arman hi sir what is refractoring? thanks

Comment: To consider restructuring your code. Because what you have provided above is hard to read. You are not following naming conventions. You can also store those file directories above into two variables. If I am right, you can condense the code into a significantly fewer lines of code without sacrificing the functionality.

Comment: @Arman this is just the a part of a code..can you help me if I provide the whole codes? I tried simplifying it but it just runs the same.

Comment: Too many `if-else` means try to find a better more elegant (less coding) solution. My advice is to re-think from the beginning your solution. There are two fundamental things in coding 1.must work 2.must be elegant. Your code is (sorry) ugly.

Comment: @valter hi sir can you suggest sir on what possible solutions I can do with my codes? thanks

Comment: You have to learn how to debug your program. Place breakpoints to various places to see if you get the expected values e.g before each if-else statement see if the text of the textboxes is the correct one. Next check if the code goes to the if or to the else statement e.g if you expect the code to go to the `if statement` but instead goes to the `else` one the comparison is wrong.

Comment: @valter I checked it already sir if all of the textboxes are filled eventhough I satisfy the statement it always goes to the else.

Comment: Jens gave you a solution and you ignored it! `isNot Nothing` is wrong. change it to `tb1.Text IsNot ""` and all the others

Comment: The problem maybe in the tb1,2,.. text. Insert a richtextbox in `form4`. Before all the `if-else` statements write: RichTextBox1.AppendText(tb1.text + vbCr), RichTextBox1.AppendText(tb2.text + vbCr).... and see if the text is correct

Comment: @valter I already tried it and it is still the same..see my above reply to Jens :)

Comment: which `if-else` statement has the problem. The tb.Text ="" or the comparison one? In the comparison you dont need both. Choose `frm1.TextBox.Text.Equals(tb.Text)` or `frm1.TextBox.Text=tb.Text` Also edit your question with what you have now.

Comment: @valter I cannot insert a richtextbox in form4 because it only has a buttons in it and labels :) If i left the textboxes empty it will function correctly and if all the textboxes has values it will all go to the else statement

Comment: @valter the comparison one :)

Comment: `Dim tb1 = frm3.TextBox1` is wrong. You have to `Dim tb1 As TextBox` and then set it to `frm3.TextBox1`. The same with the other `tb's`

Comment: @valter Hi sir I tried it but it is still the same :(

Comment: Edit your question with the code you are trying now.

Comment: @valter I already edited it sir :)

Comment: You still have not corrected `tb.Text IsNot Nothing`!

Comment: @valter sir I already corrected it awhile ago according to Jens solution but it acts the same way as IsNot Nothing that is why I reverted it back.

Comment: You have to see if `frm1.TextBox.Text` and `tb.Text` are the correct ones prior to comparison otherwise the discusion is void. Increase form4 size(just for testing) and insert the richtextbox. Append all text in it to see if it is the correct one.It is as simple as that.

Comment: @valter hi sir I did it and the text were correct

Comment: `tb.Text IsNot Nothing` is WRONG!!

Comment: @valter I replaced tb.Text IsNot Nothing with = "" in an If Not statement and then when I run the program many of the pictureboxes DISAPPEARED :o

Comment: Your code is full of errors. This particular problem is an evidence of that. Create a new project and add two forms and just two textboxes one for each form(and pictureboxes). Check if it works for this minimal test.If you make it work expanded it as you want.

Comment: @valter I created this project for almost 1 year now if I start it from scratch it like saying that to stop making this project :( I think this code has a solution but until now no one can solve it

Answer (score 0):

I tried you're code and to make it work I needed to change a few things.

1e change If tb1.Text IsNot Nothing Then to:
 
If Not tb1.Text = "" Then" "Otherwise the else didn't work if I erased the textbox"

2e I needed to change frm1 to Form1 and frm5 to Form5"It gave me errors"

3e if you use If (frm1.TextBox2.Text.Equals(tb1.Text)) And frm1.TextBox2.Text = tb1.Text Then
"aren't you checking 2 times for the same ?"

so change it to:
If (Form1.TextBox2.Text.Equals(tb1.Text)) Then

Then the code works and does what it needs to do.

```
   If Not tb1.Text = "" Then
        If (Form1.TextBox2.Text.Equals(tb1.Text)) Then
            Form5.PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("D:\checkmark.jpg")
        Else
            Form5.PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("D:\crossmark.jpg")

        End If
    Else
        Form5.PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("D:\crossmark.jpg")
    End If
```